# Бот не вызывает меню

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Бот не переходит в следующее подменю, с чем может быть связано? Бот переходит в подменю при выборе языка, но не реагирует когда выбираю следующие категории:

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot("")

#Запускаем команду старт и выбор языка
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2, resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('English')
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Русский')
    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Назад/Escape')
    markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберете язык\Select a language ', reply_markup=markup)
#Сценарий после выбора языка
#Русский
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start_categorial(message):
    if message.text == ' Русский':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4, resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Поесть')
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Музеи')
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Концерты')
        btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Кино')
        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Куда идем? ', reply_markup=markup)
#Выбор категории
@bot.message_handler (content_types = ['text'])
def start_categorical(message):
    # Еда
    if message.text == "Поесть":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn_lent = types.KeyboardButton('Фаст Фуд')
        btn_plit = types.KeyboardButton('Кафе')
        btn_stlb = types.KeyboardButton('Рестораны')
        btn_cold = types.KeyboardButton('Бары')
        markup.add(btn_lent, btn_plit, btn_stlb, btn_cold)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите тип заведения', reply_markup=markup)
bot.polling()
```

Comment: Так у вас обработчик один на все сообщения с текстом `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])`, он вызывает первую функцию с этим обработчиком и все. Можете указывать в обработчике какие-то фильтры, соответствующие теме. Или помнить контекст, т.е. что пользователь выбирал. Или погуглите про машину состояний, у этой библиотеке она есть

Comment: Почитал, спасибо, помогло. В итоге решил проблему добавив bot.register_next_step_handler(message, start_categorical)

Comment: Вы молодец, что разобрались :) Сделайте, пожалуйста, сами ответ на вашу проблему :)

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил добавив  в конец кода строку bot.register_next_step_handler(message, start_categorical)

```
def start_categorical(message):
    # Еда
    if message.text == "Поесть":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn_lent = types.KeyboardButton('Фаст Фуд')
        btn_plit = types.KeyboardButton('Кафе')
        btn_stlb = types.KeyboardButton('Рестораны')
        btn_cold = types.KeyboardButton('Бары')
        markup.add(btn_lent, btn_plit, btn_stlb, btn_cold)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, start_categorical)
```